# If statement with OR and isset Operator?

Tags: php

I'm working with two variables.  A session variable and a user variable.

I want my system to work like this:

`if ($TicketArray['PostName'] !== $Username) { die("") }`

but I want this to be overridden when `$_SESSION['Administration']` is isset. So I've come up with this:

```
if ($TicketArray['PostName'] !== $Username OR (!isset($_SESSION['Administration'])))
{
 die("");
}
```

But this kills the script when username does equal the postname, and whether the session for administration is set.. How would i construct a if statement which contains the following:

Does not equal to

or

is not set

OR
if Postname does not equal to the $Username but the $_SESSION['Administration']; isset; the person with the set session can view the ticket?

Answer (score 4):

I think you just want to use `&&` instead of `||` (or `or`).

```
if ($TicketArray['PostName'] !== $Username && !isset($_SESSION['Administration']))
{
     die("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(! isset($_SESSION['Administration']))
{
 if($TicketArray['PostName'] !== $Username)
 {
  die();
 }
}
```

**OR**

```
if(($TicketArray['PostName'] !== $Username) && (! isset($_SESSION['Administration'])))
{
 die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Could have a nested if statement.. Example follows:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['Administration']))
{
  if ($TicketArray['PostName'] !== $Username)
  {
   die("");
  }
}
```

This script will check if the session is not set, if the session is not set then the chunk will check the username compared to the PostName.

This saves a complex if statement (if what you've asked is even possible)